# Is there a formula/theory for writing country licks/riffs?

Tags: guitar, theory, country-and-western

Is there a formula/theory for writing country licks/riffs, and where can I find it?

Comment: Go fishing frequently, patronize outdoor parties in rural locations, drink heavily, spend days driving a pickup truck, and most of all, hope that your woman cheats on you and leaves you for someone else. Then pick up a guitar, but be sure never to use more than three chords in one song.

Comment: I have to disagree with you Wheat, I think it has to have a train, someone in jail, and a gun, but the rest sounds right like your woman cheating on you.

Comment: Your comments are hilarious Wheat, and filzilla, though filzilla's sounds more like a gunslinger ballad than a country song! :)

Answer (score 5):

It's the same formula/theory to write any music: listen to it. Listen to as much as you can and get it in your head. I have been trying to write and improvise solos on guitar for country and it is really difficult coming from a rock background. Country guitarist use reverse bends, major pentatonics and play with the chord changes targeting notes of those chords in the songs. So I had to really listen hard and practice starting with Johnny Cash guitar licks.

Try http://www.countryguitar.com/

Comment: The major blues scale is also something to look into.

Answer (score 2):

The other thing they really like to do is hybrid picking, to get all those major sixth double stops, etc. If you learn that technique, it'll be a whole lot easier to sound like a country virtuoso.